# Mounting all removable drives in one location

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, mount

How can I automatically mount all removable drives in a folder (for example /mnt) and merge them together?

I know merging multiple mounts is possible as per [this](https://serverfault.com/q/191299/462421) question but I want to automatically mount all partitions of all plugged in removable drives and then merge them together in another folder automatically.

I heard of fstab rules but I wasn't able to find a way to reliably achieve this.

Is there a way to (easily) do this on Raspbian Stretch with root access?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Ideally, the mount should be writeable and allow creating new files. The actual physical storage created files are written to is not very important.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_mount I can't comment on how well it works or if it is enabled in the stock kernel.  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/282393/25985

Comment: @goldilocks From the stackexchange link you provided, mhddfs looks like what I'm looking for. Any idea how to implement it in my use case?

Comment: I've never used any of that, I'm just aware it exists.  I do not think it is very widely used.  You would be better off asking about it on U&L (where that other question is from).  Raspbian is more or less stock Debian, although the kernel is not configured the same.  But if it allows for this the method would be whatever it is for Debian.